# Write Xmp metadata back to file

Tags: c#, .net, metadata, xmp, metadata-extractor

I'm using an image processing API which resizes and reformats an image from jpg to png. During this process the image loses the metadata.

Is there a way to write the metadata back to file. 
I can get the xmp metadata from the original but now I need to write it back to the new file.

This is my code so far using the metadata-extractor framework for .Net

```
public static void ReadXmpData(string fileLocation)
    {
        var xmpDirectory = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(fileLocation).OfType<XmpDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();

        foreach (var property in xmpDirectory.XmpMeta.Properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Path:\t{(property.Path != null ? property.Path.Trim() : property.Path)}\n" +
                                $"Namespace:\t{(property.Namespace != null ? property.Namespace.Trim() : property.Namespace)}\n" +
                                $"Value:\t{(property.Value != null ? property.Value.Trim() : property.Value)} \n\n\n");
        }
    }
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Edit: I am aware that metadata-extractor does not yet support the writing of xmp data

Answer (score 0):

Use [ImageMagick.net](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET) which will do image transformations without destroying the exif or xmp metadata. I use this for major film/tv studio images and works great.